# Passing proc name and arguments as list in TCL

Tags: list, arguments, tcl, proc

I have proc A, that have three parameters, and proc B that have a flexible number of parameters, since proc B could be anything. My problem is how to invoke proc B from within proc A. Currently I am doing:

```
proc B {a b c d to n} {
    do something that is right since I can call B individually and it works
}

set listB [list B a b c d to n]

proc A {a b listB} {
    do something
    if {$listB != 0} {
       execute proc B
    }
}
```

The problem is that I cannot execute B. In order to execute B I have tried:

```
$listB
[set listB]
[join $listB " "]
[concat $listB]
```

All of them fails with the same error because for TCL I am trying to use a command with name

```
"B a b c d to n"
```

What I am trying to achieve is the same that works here:

```
bind $uf.infid <Return> [list B a b c d to n]
```

-- UPDATE --
I should have mentioned that the name of proc B also can change, since I am trying to make proc A as general as posible. That is why the name of proc B is the first element in the list used as argument for proc A. Nevertheless

```
{*}$listB
```

does the job. Thanks Brad Lanam!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

proc A accepts three arguments, two normal and a list.
proc B accepts multiple arguments, not an argument that is a list.

Considering the large number of arguments passed to proc B, I think you 
would be better off re-writing proc B to accept an argument that is a list.

In general, if you have a list and you need to pass the individual arguments
to a procedure, you use the expansion operator `{*}` to expand the list
into a set of individual words.

```
proc A { a b listB } {
   B {*}$listB
}
```

In older versions of Tcl, the eval operator was required

```
proc A { a b listB } {
   eval B $listB
}
```

If proc B is rewritten

```
proc B { mylist } {
   foreach {val} $mylist {
      ...
   }
}
proc A { a b listB } {
    B $listB
}
```

(This can get very confusing to talk about, as B has an argument list that
is a list of words, not an argument that is a list, so I have avoided using
list except as a reference to the particular structure.)